# Click all with javascript document.getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the Javascript code:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('toggleFriendRelationship'); 
for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
    inputs[i].click(); 
}
```

I am trying to click all buttons on the page with `toggleFriendRelationship`.

Relevant source code:

```
<button class="btn-tab" data-capture="toggleFriendRelationship"
   title="Toggle friend relationship">
    <span>F<span class="full-label">riend</span>
   </span>
 </button>
```

Here are the screenshots from the website source:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/frLZR.png

Comment: Possible to display the relevant source code? What you have here isn't enough to answer your question. could you also give more detail in your question as i'm not sure what it is you're asking...

Comment: I'm in console.

Relevant source code: <button class="btn-tab" data-capture="toggleFriendRelationship" title="Toggle friend relationship"><span>F<span class="full-label">riend</span></span></button>

Comment: I am trying to click all the buttons that apply to toggleFriendRelationship, but 

javascript:var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('toggleFriendRelationship'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }

isn't doing the trick.

Comment: I have a little bit of an expansion on this question.

Comment: There is an earlier data-capture argument, say its either data-relationship="friend" OR data-relationship="notafriend".

How do I implement 

$('button[data-capture="toggleFriendRelationship"]').click();

so that it only clicks ones that say "notafriend" in the data-relationship earlier? Same class.

Answer (score 1):

toggleFriendRelationship starts with 't' - you're searching for ToggleFriendRelationship which start with 'T' - therefore, you wont find anything in getElementsByClassName

edit: actually you have NOTHING with that class name! you have data-capture attribute on the button, but nothing close to toggleFriendRelationship in the class

try:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('button[data-capture="toggleFriendRelationship"]');
```

Comment: The class name is 'btn-tab', still, wont pickup the data-capture property.

Comment: yeah, I just realised it was data-capture that had the errant string, and class had nothing like the string he's looking for - hence the edit

Comment: Exactly. The issue is that 3 different buttons are in the same class. If each button had its own class, I could easily run document.getElementsByClassName. 

The issue is that I need to go deeper, and get the element by the data-capture attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Got it.

```
$('button[data-capture="toggleFriendRelationship"]').click();
```